# Sharing application between Linux distros in a multi-boot

Tags: multi-boot, gui, application-launch

I'm multi booting Arch Linux, Fedora and Ubuntu, and would like to use applications installed in one of them in the other as well. The terminal-only applications can be run easily by chrooting, but not the ones that require a GUI. Is there a way to share such applications between OSes?

Comment: Is there a way to share such applications between OSes?    ... You can try virtual machines. Even then sharing applications between machines is difficult. What you are describing is a client server application and that needs a client server setup.

Comment: This seems like an X Y problem: what are you trying to resolve/solve by doing this? _(please add to your question)_ @John's comment seems like it'd be the best route - are the compiled binaries even compatible across the three distros? If not, it rules out creating a separate partition to install the applications for sharing across the distros, but a separate partition could be a possible solution if the purpose for doing so is accessing config files, projects, etc. on one across another _(for example, I have my home directory on its own partition that is shared across all the VMs I run)_.

Comment: You have 3 ways to do this: Client Server as noted; Virtual machines and log into the machine that has the app from the host; dual boot- start the machine that has the app.